# How can I run my Spring Boot web application in exploded mode in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-applications, war, exploded

I want to made my spring boot application to be exploded so I can make changes in the code and watch it at the moment. I try it a lot of method but any of them works.. I need some help with this. Thank you.

I want to work dynamically with my Spring Boot application so I can save lot of time without stopping and running every time I made changes.

Comment: Just run it from your IDE or use maven or gradle to run your app and use Spring Boot Devtools for auto restart/reload.